# Iot Hub device authentification for blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

I'm struggling a lot with my blob storage on Azure. I'm on client side and have not access to connection string or storage connection string. When I'm uploading files to my blob storage I can use my device client that is authentificated with a X509 certificate:

```
DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate _auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate(deviceId, x509Certificate);
```

Then I can get my sas uri to upload the file:

```
var sasUri = deviceClient.GetFileUploadSasUriAsync(new FileUploadSasUriRequest { BlobName = dstPath + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(path) });
```

My problem is that there is no "GetFileDownloadSasUriAsync" or similar. I have no backend to get a custom sas uri. I have no front-end to use Azure AD login or similar. How can I authenticate with a X509 certificate to download a specific file from blob storage?